# Wi-Fi GO! Stuck at Waiting connection. Remote control

Tags: wireless-networking

This is a screenshot of my iphone screen:
[image]

This is the page about Wi-Fi GO! From my motherboard's website.(Scroll Down)
https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/X99-DELUXE-II/overview/

I've installed the app on my mobile and the suite on my computer.

What is the problem, how can I fix it?

Wi-Fi GO! is used to control the computer using the phone.

Comment: So you are trying to remote control your phone, correct?

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to remote control my computer.

Comment: ah duh, lol. Have you tried reinstalling the mobile app?

Comment: It worth the try I guess, I'll do so this evening

Comment: Write me a good anwser @Mr. Hargrove. So I can give you the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of the mobile remote control application, doing a reinstall could fix the problem of hanging when trying to connect to the Remote Desktop.

Comment: "could" I'll try next time.